# How to access datagrid in pywinauto for .net app?

Tags: pywinauto

I upgraded to 0.6.6 of pywinauto after looking at the release notes. I am working on a .net app which has a datagridview control and I am trying to get hold of the control. The automation id is dynamic(every time app is launched). I am unable to get hold of the datagridview control and always getting pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError. I am not sure if control_type should be table or datagrid or datagridview for trying further. Some things that I have tried

```
    x=app.window(auto_id='FrmAllTimeSaleFilter').child_window(control_type="Table", class_name="WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").ItemCount()

    x=app.window(auto_id='FrmAllTimeSaleFilter').child_window(auto_id="1314290", class_name="WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.141b42a_r9_ad1").ItemCount()

x=app.window(auto_id='FrmAllTimeSaleFilter').child_window(control_type="Table").PrintControlIdentifiers()

x=app.window(auto_id='FrmAllTimeSaleFilter').child_window(control_type="DataItem").PrintControlIdentifiers()
```

Also didnt find any documentation as well on https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/controls_overview.html and the methods available for it.

[image: inspect snapshot of the control attached]

```
app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path = confnestTraderExePath)
print("connected to application")
app.window_(title_re = "Time.*").print_control_identifiers()
sys.exit()
```

Output

```
connected to application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 256, in __resolve_control
    criteria)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 458, in wait_until_passes
    raise err
pywinauto.timings.TimeoutError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ts.py", line 758, in <module>
    app.window_(title_re = "Time.*").print_control_identifiers()
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 595, in print_control_identifiers
    this_ctrl = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)[-1]
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 259, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\timings.py", line 436, in wait_until_passes
    func_val = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 201, in __get_ctrl
    dialog = self.backend.generic_wrapper_class(findwindows.find_element(**criteria[0]))
  File "C:\python35\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 87, in find_element
    raise ElementNotFoundError(kwargs)
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'backend': 'uia', 'title_re': 'Time.*', 'process': 5712}
```

Update 2:
Using the code below, I can access the datagridview using backend="uia".

```
tsWindow=app.window_(title_re = "MYAPP.*").child_window(title_re=".*Sales Filter")
count=tsWindow.DataGridView.item_count()
for i in range(0,count-1):
    print(tsWindow.DataGridView.cell(i,0))
```

But I get following output. I am not getting the data in the grid but instead it returns something like this. How do I process this?

```
connected to application
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - 'Time Row 0', DataItem
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - 'Time Row 1', DataItem
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - 'Time Row 2', DataItem
uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - 'Time Row 3', DataItem
```

Comment: Which backend do you use for Application object?

Comment: If I use app = Application(backend="uia").connect(path = appPath) then I get ElementNotFoundError for basic stuff like print_control_identifiers for the app window.  So I am using it this way  app = Application().connect(path = appPath) which atleast gives me output for print_control_identifiers

Comment: The hierarchy is different for these backends. So maybe another names are needed. Please post full technical description for the error with `backend="uia"`. This is the only way to work with DataGridView.

Comment: Updated the details in my questions. I am not even trying to access datagrid in above code. This is just for the window that has the control. Thanks

Comment: Hi @VasilyRyabov  I think I got it and you are right. The hierarchy is different. When using backend="uia", I cannot access the child window directly. So I got hold of the parent window and then searched for the child window which has the datagridview. Give me sometime now. I will check if I can access datagrid with the new approach

Comment: Hi @VasilyRyabov Can you please help me resolve with update 2 above. I am getting uia_controls.ListItemWrapper - 'Time Row 3', DataItem instead of the data from datagridview. How do I get the data from datagridview?

Comment: What `print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()])` prints?

Comment: It prints  ['MYAPP - Welcome']

Comment: Well, you have to use `app.window(title_re = ".* - Welcome").dump_tree()` (`dump_tree` is a short alias of `print_control_identifiers`).

Comment: tsWindow.DataGridView.cell(i,0) Is not.giving me cell data  i have uploaded the output in the question. How do i get datagridview data for specific cell?

Comment: How about listing children of the row? `print(tsWindow.DataGridView.cell(i,0).children())` And how about `.cell(i, 1)`, `.cell(i, 2)` etc?

Answer (score 3):

once you got the list listitemwrapper ,you can access its value

```
 listItemWrapper.legacy_proprites()['Value']
```

that should return the value of that item.

Comment: here is a more complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48223026/14244758